# Does Dovecot-LDA need the -f argument (and what is its purpose)?

Tags: email, postfix-mta, mail-server, dovecot, mail-sender

Dovecot-LDA seems to deliver mail without the -f argument, and delivered mail is identical with and without it, however many setup guides include it in the delivery command. I'm frequently seeing error messages regarding invalid -f arguments, and I figure that removing it from my delivery command should fix this.

**How does the -f argument change Dovecot-LDA's behaviour, and do I really need to provide it?**

Comment: Could you provide samples of the invalid addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-f` sets "envelope sender".  It is email address used in `SMTP` protocol `MAIL FROM:` command to indicate where delivery failure notifications should be send.

AFAIK dovecot-lda does not use it itself **but** may be used by sieve filters.
AFAIK Most MTA/SMTP servers put envelope sender address in `Return-Path:` header before the final delivery (e.g. before passing the message to `dovecot-lda`).

My rule of thumb suggestion: Try to fix your problem.
**IF** it is hard to fix **AND** you do not use envelope sender in sieve scripts
 **THEN**  you may remove `-f` option from dovecot-lda command line parameters.

Comment: Is it really used by sieve? It seems like I can create rules regarding headers that are not passed to `dovecot-lda` via command line. I haven't been able to make `dovecot-lda` bounce anything so I'm not sure if it needs it to send bounce messages.

Comment: It **MAY** be used by sieve scripts in filtering/sorting rules.